# Custom annotation for request param is not recognizing while testing the controller method

Tags: spring

Request Param validated with custom annotation `@ValidNumber` which is created by using the below code.

```
@Constraint(validatedBy=NumberValidater.class)
@Target(Field, Parameter,..)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface ValidNumber {
    String message() default 
                "{javax.validation.constraints.ValidNumber.message}"
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends PayLoad>[] payload() default {};
}
```

NumberValidator Class

```
public NumberValidator implements <ConstraintValidator, Integer>{
    public void intialize(ValidNumber constraintAnnotation){
    }
    public boolean isValid(Integer number, ConstraintValidatorContext context){
        return(number !=null && number !=0)
    }
```

Configuration Class:

```
@Bean
public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
         return new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
}
```

Controller Class is:

```
@RestController
@Validated
public StudentController{
    @RequestMapping(value="rollNumber", method=GET)
    public Student getStudentHallticket(@ValidNumber (message= "Invalid RollNumber)
        @RequestParam(vallue = "rollNumber") Integer rollNumber{    
        return service.getHallTicket();
    }
```

Java Class executed perfectly and validated the input value, but the test class is not correctly validating the input param.

Test Case:

```
class StudentSpec extends Specification{

    @Autowired
    private StudentController studentController;
    @Autowired
    private LocalValidatorFoctoryBean validator
    private MockMvc mockmvc

    def setup(){      
        mockmvc.MockMvcBuilders.standloneSetup(studentController).setValidator(validator).build()
    }       
    def getStudentHallTicket(){

        given:
        def rollNumber = ""

        when:
        def response = mockmvc.perform(get("/rollNumber/").param("rollNumber", rollNumber)

        then:
        response.andExpect(status().isBadRequest())
    }
}



When executed it is giving `isOk()` instead of `isBadRequest()` status that means request parameter not validating when it is null.   
My question is, how do I make sure the custom annotation is available for testing class?
```

Comment: The only configuration needed is adding the MethodValidationPostProcessor, have you created MethodValidationPostProcessor bean?

Comment: Yes, please MethodValidationPostProcessor has been added java class in configuration.                                                                                          
  @Bean
public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
         return new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
}                                                                                                                      
   Do you want me to configure the same in test class also

Comment: yes make sure this bean is exist during test env.

Comment: @Bhushan, can you please help what I can do for that

Comment: can you please create a git demo project for it and share the git repo link so I or other devs can get more info about it and  will help you.